# How to include .jar in classpath so to have library included in compilation

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, jar

I have a folder full of `*.jar` files that I want to be included during compilation no matter what directory I'm in. As I currently understand it, and this could be completely wrong, I would have to make this change in `/etc/environment`. So my `/etc/environment` currently looks like this:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:
/usr/local/games:/~/Java/algs4/bin"
JAVA_HOME="usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java"
CLASSPATH="~/Java/algs4/bin:."
```

where `~/Java/algs4/bin` is the directory where my `.jar`s are. But when I try to compile a program that uses these libraries javac doesn't recognize the libraries. What am I fudging?

java version is 1.7.0_51

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Here's my code that I'm trying to get to work

### FixedCapacityStackOfStrings.java

```
  public class FixedCapacityStackOfStrings{

    private String[] a;
    private int N;

    public FixedCapacityStackOfStrings(int cap){
        a = new String[cap];
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){ return N == 0;}

    public int size()       { return N;}

    public void push(String item)
    {
        a[N++] = item;
    }

    public String pop()
    {
        return a[--N];
    }

    //test client
    public static void main(String[] args){
        FixedCapacityStackOfStrings s;
        s = new FixedCapacityStackOfStrings(100);
        while(!StdIn.isEmpty()){
            String item = StdIn.readString();
            StdOut.println(item);
            if (!item.equals("-"))
                s.push(item);
            else if(!s.isEmpty()) StdOut.print(s.pop() + " " );
        }
        StdOut.println("(" + s.size() + " left on stack)");
    }
}
```

Where StdOut and StdIn are the included in one of the `.jar` files in `/bin`. When I compile I get the error `cannot find symbol` for StdIn and StdOut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should include all jar files in the classpath.

```
CLASSPATH=.
for j in ~/Java/algs4/bin/*.jar; do CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$j done
export CLASSPATH
```

CLASSPATH environment is ':' separated entries, both jar/zip file and directory.

directory is used to search .class files, not jar file

Comment: I made the changes and logged out and tried to compile but got the same result as before. I added more info on my problem to my original post.

Comment: `cannot find symbol` means the class cannot be found in this file. you must import the classes you use. before `public class FixedCapacityStackOfStrings` line, add `import com.example.pkg.StdIn; import com.example.pkg.StdOut` where com.example.pkg is the package containing StdIn and StdOut

Answer (score 1):

Use CLASSPATH="~/Java/algs4/bin/*:."

Comment: Made this change but it didn't do the trick. Would I have to make any declarations to import the libraries in my java class?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this documentation.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

*Class path entries can contain the basename wildcard character *, which is considered equivalent to specifying a list of all the files in the directory with the extension .jar or .JAR. For example, the class path entry foo/* specifies all JAR files in the directory named foo. A classpath entry consisting simply of * expands to a list of all the jar files in the current directory.*